How to build an executable with PyInstaller that is works with WSLg
I was making a basic app for visualizing the VMAF report of a video encoding using a graph with matplotlib. However, I ran into an issue with PyInstaller.
Seems bc of the way that PyInstaller works, it does not correctly package the right things to make the final executable compatible with WSLg. Has anyone had this issue before and figured out how to get it to work? Its not an issue with the Python code, bc if I run it using the python3 command it shows the matplotlib graph fine with WSLg built into my Windows 11 install.
I use Ubuntu WSL for most of my development so it'd be a bummer if I had to swap over to PowerShell just to run this one program. I am trying to install it to /usr/local/bin so I can use it seamlessly any time, hence I am building to an executable with PyInstaller.
Here is the git repo in case you need to take a look at anything. It is quite a simple program so do no think there is much need to explain how it works.
Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Cheers,
Matthew

I realized I never posted the exception that I was having:
I started with:

UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown

then after installing some stuff got:

Error processing file: No module named 'PIL._tkinter_finder'

Welp I managed to figure it out on my own:
Firstly if you are having any issues make sure you have everything you need installed:

pip install Pillow

or if you already have it installed upgrade it

pip install --upgrade Pillow

then make sure you have python3-tk installed as well

sudo apt-get install python3-tk

I am using auto generated spec files so for me I just needed to add a few args to the pyinstaller command:
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=PIL --hidden-import=PIL._tkinter_finder --hidden-import=tkinter "$(SOURCE_DIR)/$(MAIN_SCRIPT)" 

If you are NOT auto generating the spec file then you can just modify the spec file's hiddenimports field:
a = Analysis(
    ['../../src/vmaf-grapher.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['PIL', 'PIL._tkinter_finder', 'tkinter'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)

And voila, your executable works with WSLg.
You can check out the git commit here.
Cheers,
Matthew
